# Bash scripts prints numbers at the beginning of the output

Tags: bash, sh

I have created a bash script to verify if Xcode process is running:

```
#! /bin/bash
PROCESS_NAME=Xcode

if pgrep $PROCESS_NAME; then
    echo "Xcode is running";
else
    echo "Xcode is not running";
if
```

But when Xcode is running, the bash scripts get this output:

```
16115
16119
Xcode is running
```

How can I remove the two lines with the numbers?

I have no idea the numbers what mean or why the numbers are printed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pgrep` is printing the process IDs of the matching processes. Tell it to be quiet with `-q`.

```
if pgrep -q "$PROCESS_NAME"; then
    echo "Xcode is running"
else
    echo "Xcode is not running"
fi
```

If your version of `pgrep` does not support `-q`, just redirect its standard output to `/dev/null`:

```
if pgrep "$PROCESS_NAME" > /dev/null ; then
    echo "Xcode is running"
else
    echo "Xcode is not running"
fi
```

Comment: That's odd; it's standard for `grep` and the BSD version of `pgrep` implements it. Are you using the GNU version of `pgrep` somehow?

Comment: @chepner: Yup, doesn't seem to have it, https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep

Comment: Checking for Xcode implies to me that this is running on macOS, though, which should be using the BSD version.

Comment: I tried with `pgrep -q "$PROCESS_NAME"` and it works. I'm using macOS 10.12.1. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just redirect standard ouput to `/dev/null`:

```
pgrep ls >/dev/null && echo "Xcode is running" || echo "Xcode is not running"
```

Answer (score 1):

The numbers are part of the `stdout` the command `pgrep` produces which you can suppress by re-directing it to the `/dev/null`

```
#!/bin/bash
PROCESS_NAME=Xcode

if pgrep "$PROCESS_NAME" >/dev/null; then
    echo "Xcode is running";
else
    echo "Xcode is not running";
fi
```

A typo in the last line of your script, which should be `fi`.

Also you can go one step ahead and suppress, error messages if any thrown by doing `2>&1`, i.e.

```
if pgrep "$PROCESS_NAME" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
```